# Vagrant on Windows 10: Cannot find variable with the name 'AmsiContext'

Tags: windows, powershell, vagrant

As currently cannot answer this -> [Powershell: Cannot find a variable with the name 'AmsiContext'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70172291/powershell-cannot-find-a-variable-with-the-name-amsicontext)

The issue can be fixed temporarily by changing (assuming you have **PowerShell** 5 or higher):
**C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\2.2.19\gems\vagrant-2.2.19\lib\vagrant\util\powershell.rb**

```ruby
      # Returns the version of PowerShell that is installed.
      #
      # @return [String]
      def self.version
        if !defined?(@_powershell_version)
          command = [
            executable,
            "-NoLogo",
            "-NoProfile",
            "-NonInteractive",
            "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass",
            "-Command",
            "Write-Output $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"
          ].flatten

          version = nil
          timeout = ENV["VAGRANT_POWERSHELL_VERSION_DETECTION_TIMEOUT"].to_i
          if timeout < 1
            timeout = DEFAULT_VERSION_DETECTION_TIMEOUT
          end
          begin
            r = Subprocess.execute(*command,
              notify: [:stdout, :stderr],
              timeout: timeout,
            ) {|io_name,data| version = data}
          rescue Vagrant::Util::Subprocess::TimeoutExceeded
            LOGGER.debug("Timeout exceeded while attempting to determine version of Powershell.")
          end

          @_powershell_version = 5
#version
        end
        @_powershell_version
      end
```

Comment: This looks like an answer to the linked question. If that's the case, then it shouldn't have been posted as a question.

Comment: That's could be great if i could with lower reputation points to answer and give feedback ;-) but because i cannot, just wanted to give the knowledge to anyone that needs it...
its actually a solution to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70172291/powershell-cannot-find-a-variable-with-the-name-amsicontext) `Powershell: Cannot find a variable with the name 'AmsiContext'`